# Make a GUI Interface

Tags: c++, user-interface, glut, ubuntu-10.04

Hi I have made a game and I have used OpenGL for its graphics.the OS is ubuntu 10.04.
The only thing left is to make a user interface so as to directly receive the requisite inputs from the user rather than from the terminal.

Can sm1 please tell me any good links to go to !!!!or any software that can ease my work !
thnx.

Answer (score 1):

hello 
my suggestion is use QT or GTK+ to create a gui .
it is so easy you can learn QT from it's own API and you can find a good Document for GTK+ in it website .

Comment: also if you want you will be able to use opengl but it is harder than others

Answer (score 0):

The [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) graphical user interface system supports OpenGL rendering.